# Can't locate Net/SNMP.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Net::SNMP module

Tags: perl, netbeans, net-snmp

as to the title, i faced error Can't locate Net/SNMP.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Net::SNMP module while trying to run my perl script from netbeans. Its clearly says i need to install Net::SNMP module. But, i have already installed net-snmp module on my windows tho, and configure it by following [this](http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB25949&actp=search) tutorial . is Net::SNMP and net-snmp different? if yes, how to install Net::SNMP on windows 8.1 and 10 ? i already installed activeperl and also net-snmp on my computer. feels hopeless because already done some research yet still unable to found solution to solve this problem.

any help are greatly appreciated. thank you

Comment: What command did you run to install the module? [Net::SNMP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SNMP), a pure Perl module available on CPAN, is not the same as [SNMP.pm](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/perl-SNMP-README.html), the Perl API for the Net-SNMP C library.

Answer (score 2):

You should print `@INC` magic array to know where perl looks for installed modules. Check whether `Net/SNMP.pm` is somewhere there.

To add another path to `@INC` use `-I` switch for perl or `PERL5LIB` environment variable.